# JSON Formatting: Triggering a flow from SharePoint list without a button

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, json-formatting

I would like to know if there is any chance with JSON to automatically trigger a flow from a SharePoint list without a button. Just when a new item is created.

The solution with the buttons is as:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edf627d9-20f4-45ba-8bc9-4494bf2ff1be\"}"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "attributes": {
        "iconName": "Flow"
      },
      "style": {
        "padding-right": "6px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "It's Flow Time!"
    }
  ]
}
```

Would be possible to define a condition like the two columns, Modified == Created, to automatically call a flow when a new item is created?

Also there is option to call the flow via http:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "Create Unique ID",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover",
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "=if([$Created]==[$Modified],'https://prod-xxx.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','')"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "text-decoration": "none",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "color": "red",
    "cursor": "pointer"
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Fernando,

Power automate has a standard sharepoint list flow trigger of 'When a new item is created':

[image]

In the settings, the trigger conditions can be set using a formula:

[image]

So long as this flow is activated, when a new item is added (and providing trigger conditions are met) it will run - no JSON coding needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeap, thank you, if we create a flow per list we need 1200 flows in our Project Online instance: 3 lists per site x 400 projects. Not working for us. On top of that, the user has to configure this manually for every new project, when a new project is created (new project site), we do not expect the Project Managers to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, thank you, if we create a flow per list we need 1200 flows in our Project Online instance: 3 lists per site x 400 projects. Not working for us. On top of that, the user has to configure this manually for every new project, when a new project is created (new project site), we do not expect the Project Managers to do this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! FYI: This should be a comment on @Bh1208's answer rather than an answer itself.

Comment: I don't recommend solving this with Flow. Even if you did find a way to provision that many flows, maintenance would be a nightmare. Also, flows that don't run for 90 days will just shut off so you'll be constantly trying to turn them back on if there aren't frequent updates. To @Bh1208's point, however, this has nothing to do with formatting. An `executeFlow` action will only happen when manually pressed and still requires the flows to be associated to the list.

Comment: A better solution is likely to use webhooks with a custom Azure Function to manage subscriptions with a registration call as part of your provisioning. It's more complex, but your solution falls outside of normal use case for Power Automate.

Comment: Hi @theChrisKent ! Thank you for having a look! I thought with JSON we could automate this without a button to call the flow with some condition. Do you know if the `executeFlow` action accepts parameters? I definitely have to research on webhooks.